Bosch microwave drawer buttons (5 buttons on top left) are not working
I have a built-in Bosch drawer HMD8451UC/01 microwave. The first 5 buttons on top left are not working. It’s coincidence that they don’t work one day after a very humid day (97% humidity).
One of buttons is the “open” button and hence I’m not able to open it. The gear will be activated to open if I exert force to pull it.
I’ve turned off power for a day, cleaned the inside/seal and the electric ribbon to the board but doesn’t solve the issue. Don’t think the latch is the issue as when I stopped the microwave midway (close button still works), the open button still don’t work.
Is this an issue of the panel, electric board or switch? I’m not electrician but I am pretty handy. What do you think I should do to fix it?


If they're touch switches, i.e., depend on body capacitance to trigger, it might indeed be moisture from cooked food causing the issue. You might try using a hair dryer to dry that area. N.B. Do not get the plastic too hot! Warm gently for a while and test to see if it helped.

Which area are you referring to? Yes, they are  touch switches, there’s no mechanical button. Not sure if it’s cause of moisture cause it’s been 4-5 days now since I have the issue and I’ve not used the microwave

Could just be a bum panel.

There are different types of touch switches. Those that depress just a little bit are mechanical switches; those that work when touched by a conductive object (e.g., finger or stylus) are capacitive switches -- and  little moisture in one of those shorts it.

This is the conductive kind. If it’s short, does it require replacement or it can be repaired somehow? Do you think the issues lies on the panel ?
